# SpriteSpin: how can I find the current frame number

Tags: javascript, jquery

SpriteSpin.js
I can see from: http://spritespin.ginie.eu/docs/spritespin.html

```
frame : 0,            // Initial (and current) frame number
```

But whenever I am trying to console.log(frame); it is saying frame is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

have to use this function

```
currentFrame: function(){
      return this.data.frame;
    },
```